# How to make tweetnacl work?

Tags: c

Tweetnacl's header and source files (as provided [here](https://tweetnacl.cr.yp.to/software.html)) do not match up, the `extern` functions declared in the header are not actually defined in the source file. I presume the many `#define`s in the header are the key to making sense of this, though I'm not sure how. What kind of weird format is it using? What am I missing?

Though probably a seperate issue, the source file also cannot find `randombytes` when linking, where is this function meant to be defined?

**Example:**

In `tweetnacl.h`:

```
#define crypto_hash_sha256_tweet_BYTES 32
extern int crypto_hash_sha256_tweet(unsigned char *,const unsigned char *,unsigned long long);
#define crypto_hash_sha256_tweet_VERSION "-"
#define crypto_hash_sha256 crypto_hash_sha256_tweet
#define crypto_hash_sha256_BYTES crypto_hash_sha256_tweet_BYTES
#define crypto_hash_sha256_VERSION crypto_hash_sha256_tweet_VERSION
#define crypto_hash_sha256_IMPLEMENTATION "crypto_hash/sha256/tweet"
```

The source file does not define a function called `crypto_hash_sha256_tweet`. Functionally `crypto_hash` deals with computing a hash, plus the `#define`s aren't actually used in the source file, which suggests to me there is some third component here that I am missing, e.g. some parser script that re-writes the source file to match the header.

Comment: Seriously, are you expecting people to delve into links within links and solve the problem? It is *your* problem so you should make it very easy for readers to understand the specific problem. You have been here long enough to understand why a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem is needed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Woah, chill. I'm not expecting that there is a need to delve into links, as it seems that this is an obvious thing to anyone but me as evidenced by the fact that google has not found me a single other person with the same issue. I expect this is some methodology I do not know about, so akin to someone who has never heard of make seeing a makefile for the first time. I shall however include a code excerpt to remove the need for following a link and clear up possibly ambiguity in my description of the issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane A hostile and incredibly condescending comment such as yours is not appropriate and hardly helpful, *you* have been here long enough to understand that.